# Need help on creating SSIS package for Nightly Backup and Restores of Database

Tags: sql, ssis

We had a couple of database in production server. need to restore it on Staging every night for reporting purpose. I want to know whether I can creat a SSIS package for that.

Thanks,

karthik

Comment: I think you can do those things with SQL Server management jobs. If you can avoid SSIS do yourself a favour and steer clear

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that.

Take a look at [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345390.aspx) that goes over creating or refreshing a reporting database.

If you have a more detailed question please post it.

Comment: Is there any link to guide me for creating package. Can I find a  sample package of similar type.

Comment: I would start by looking at the `Transfer Database Task` link on the page I directed you to.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141204.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use "Transfer Database Task"
I think it is much faster than backup/restore